# 浮動小数点数のバイナリファイルを作りたい

Tags: common-lisp

double-floatの値をIEEE 754に変換して、1byteずつwrite-byteするしかないでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write-sequenceを使えば、write-byteするよりは楽なことが多いですが、それよりも 
[nibbles](http://www.cliki.net/nibbles) というライブラリを利用すると簡単に作成することが可能です。

```
(ql:quickload :nibbles)


(with-open-file (out "/tmp/pi.out"
                     :direction :output
                     :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))
  (nibbles:write-ieee-double/le pi out))
;=>  3.141592653589793d0


(with-open-file (in "/tmp/pi.out" :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))
  (nibbles:read-ieee-double/le in))
;=>  3.141592653589793d0
```